Loosing an extra comma in bibliography
I'm super new here but have benefitted from various threads here in the past. So first of all thanks for all the help.
I have to admit that I actually never really learned LaTeX - more a learning by doing thing.
Now I have an issue that I can't find anything about and I hope you guys can help me.
I'm using biblatex[style=apa] which worked fine. But now I'm almost done I found out that in my bibliography in sources with two or more authors there is an extra comma that can't get rid ouf with my limited knowledge.
So the display in the PDF is

Author, A., & Author, B. (Year). [...]

however it should display:

Author, A. & Author, B. (Year). [...]

I know you guys always want a MWE so I condensed my quite full header to this:
\documentclass[11pt, listof=numbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, pagetracker, ibidtracker=constrict]{biblatex} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}



\begin{document}
 Test test test tes \parencite[vgl.][S.14]{becker} another cite \parencite[vgl.][S.56]{trauma}
 
 \printbibliography


\end{document}

with the entry:
@online{becker,
    author={Anieke Becker and Sarah Spitzer},
    date={2018},
    title = {Wissen kompakt. Unbegleitete Minderjährige Flüchtlinge},
    url = {https://www.diakonie-pfalz.de/fileadmin/user_upload/global/Wissen_kompakt/2018_Wissen_kompakt_Unbegleitete_minderjaehrige_Fluechtlinge.pdf},
    urldate = {2024-04-07}}
@book{trauma,
    author = {Trenczek, Th. and Düring, D. and Neumann-Witt, A.},
    date = {2017},
    edition = {3},
    publisher = {Richard Boorberg Verlag},
    title = {Inobhutnahme. Kriesenintervention und Schutzgewährung durch die Jugendhilfe § 8a, §§ 42a ff. SGB VIII}}

I appreciate any help...

Note that \DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa} hasn't been needed for almost five years now. Remove this line and be slightly more wary of the source that told you to use this line.
